# How to find the right Sub folder for wildcard

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I am using the code below in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
 # -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName domain.co.uk
AuthUserFile /home/****/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/****/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp



RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
Allow from 148.204.
Allow from googlebot.com google.com
satisfy any

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]*)/?(.*)::\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]


ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

This works for my fixed subdomains but not for my wildcard subdomain where I have added * in cpanel to public_html/subdomain and placed my index.php I want to the browser to find on a wildcard at public_html/subdomain/index.php
Currently its finding the public/html/index.php or nothing at all (cant find website at all)

What is wrong for the above htaccess for the subdomains?

Comment: Hi Jon - yes but there was no more room to add more questions  -is there anything wrong with above code? Thanks very much for your help Jon

Comment: Yeah, you're missing the code that I gave you when you asked the same question earlier.

Comment: hi sorry - I added the previous code by mistake. This is the htaccess including your code  - my wildcard subdomains are going to 404 page. I am getting very frustrated now - I hope you can help me Jon Lin